# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, laravel, кодировка, utf-8

Всем привет. Возникла проблема с кодировкой, но я не пойму что делать. 
Есть такой метод:

```
public function par(Request $req)
    {
        $doc = new Document($req->url,true);
        $posts = $doc->find('.btn-primary');        
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $link = $post->attr('href');
            $rest = 'http:' . $link;
            $newDoc = new Document($rest, true);

            $oldName = $newDoc->first('.btn-primary11')->text();
            $newName = substr($oldName,0,27);

            $iframe = $newDoc->first('#embed_code_textarea')->innerHtml();

            $film = new Films();
            $film->name = $newName;
            $film->link = $iframe;
            $film->save();
        }
        return response()->json();
    }
```

Вроде все работает нормально, но после того как создаю экземпляр модели Films, и записываю данные в бд, происходит эта ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка вылетает не в момент создания объекта, а на строке

```
return response()->json();
```

Метод json() требует аргументов. Например, передайте в него объект film:

```
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'film' => $film], 200);
```